# Matlab Editor becomes really slow with polynomial equations having a "combinatorial" (huge) number of terms

Tags: matlab, fortran

Suppose you need to manage a set of N polynomials which are related to the value of the previous ones. Once you have discovered their pattern (a heavy task by itself because you need to get into N=6 at least), the problem is to write the Matlab function with the equations for N=24: they eventually become so long (say when N>12) that even using the Matlab editor becomes unfeasible (it gets really slow even after increasing the heap).

So you choose to generate the equations as very long strings to be evaluated by EVAL. Your are on track but then your run out of memory by N=17 (even with 32GB of RAM).

I even used the matfile function with those huge strings to save memory.

My question is about the feasibility to do this with Fortran (and reach N=24, which is the required size of my problem). I didn't find any relevant information about really long expressions and/or really long programs (as a result of the expressions inside) that is related to Fortran, so I can only guess that those memory problems with Matlab will not appear with such a number-crunching software.

NEW LINES: Thanks so much you all for your three comments. First, I will take the recursion/memoization techniques after trying to run the N=16 problem. I will appreciate some additional information about these techniques if available.
I am dealing with this interesting problem for at least 10 days and I begun prototyping its solution with the vectorizing capabilities of Matlab, but as I told you the Matlab Editor reached its limits, while the first trials with running the script with the N=12 function were relatively fast and fine. Second, I am providing a program from the Fortran Editor I am working on now for you to look at the kind of polynomial we are dealing with.

```
    program trialerror4
implicit none

integer :: i 
integer, parameter :: H0=24
real :: dd,bd
double precision :: x0,Abar,A0,a,b,c,d,e,f                                                                         
double precision, dimension(H0) :: ex,xd 
double precision, dimension(H0+1) :: xx
xx=0.0
xx(1) = x0 

data dd,bd,x0 /0.995,0.573,2.0/ 

Abar = 0 
  A0 = 1 + bd + (dd*bd*Abar)
   a = (A0 - bd)/A0 !o(1)
Abar = a**2      
  A0 = 1 + bd + (dd*bd*Abar)
   b = (A0 - bd)/A0 !o(2)
Abar = (b**2)*(1+dd)  
  A0 = 1 + bd + (dd*bd*Abar)
   c = (A0 - bd)/A0 !o(3)
Abar = ((a**2)*(dd**(2)))+((b**2)*(dd))+((c**2)) +&
       (((-2*(a**2)*b)+((a**2)*(b**2)))*(dd**2)) + (((-2*(a**2)*c)+((a**2)*(c**2)))*(dd**2)) +&
       (((-2*(b**2)*c)+((b**2)*(c**2)))*(dd)) +&
       (((4*(a**2)*b*c)+(-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*c)+(-2*(a**2)*b*(c**2))+((a**2)*(b**2)*(c**2)))*(dd**2))
  A0 = 1 + bd + (dd*bd*Abar) !ln30
   d = (A0 - bd)/A0 !o(4)
Abar = ((a**2)*(dd**(3)))+((b**2)*(dd**(2)))+((c**2)*(dd))+((d**2)) +&
       (((-2*(a**2)*b)+((a**2)*(b**2)))*(dd**3)) + (((-2*(a**2)*c)+((a**2)*(c**2)))*(dd**3)) +&
       (((-2*(a**2)*d)+((a**2)*(d**2)))*(dd**3)) + (((-2*(b**2)*c)+((b**2)*(c**2)))*(dd**2)) +&
       (((-2*(b**2)*d)+((b**2)*(d**2)))*(dd**2)) + (((-2*(c**2)*d)+((c**2)*(d**2)))*(dd)) +&
       (((4*(a**2)*b*c)+(-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*c)+(-2*(a**2)*b*(c**2))+((a**2)*(b**2)*(c**2)))*(dd**3)) +&
       (((4*(a**2)*b*d)+(-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*d)+(-2*(a**2)*b*(d**2))+((a**2)*(b**2)*(d**2)))*(dd**3)) +&
       (((4*(a**2)*c*d)+(-2*(a**2)*(c**2)*d)+(-2*(a**2)*c*(d**2))+((a**2)*(c**2)*(d**2)))*(dd**3)) +&
       (((4*(b**2)*c*d)+(-2*(b**2)*(c**2)*d)+(-2*(b**2)*c*(d**2))+((b**2)*(c**2)*(d**2)))*(dd**2)) +&
       (((-8*(a**2)*b*c*d)+(4*(a**2)*(b**2)*c*d)+(4*(a**2)*b*(c**2)*d)+(4*(a**2)*b*c*(d**2))+& !ln40
       (-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*(c**2)*d)+(-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*c*(d**2))+(-2*(a**2)*b*(c**2)*(d**2))+&
       ((a**2)*(b**2)*(c**2)*(d**2)))*(dd**3))
  A0 = 1 + bd + (dd*bd*Abar)
   e = (A0 - bd)/A0 !o(5)
Abar = ((a**2)*(dd**(4)))+((b**2)*(dd**(3)))+((c**2)*(dd**(2)))+((d**2)*(dd))+((e**2)) +&
       (((-2*(a**2)*b)+((a**2)*(b**2)))*(dd**4)) + (((-2*(a**2)*c)+((a**2)*(c**2)))*(dd**4)) +&
       (((-2*(a**2)*d)+((a**2)*(d**2)))*(dd**4)) + (((-2*(a**2)*e)+((a**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**4)) +&
       (((-2*(b**2)*c)+((b**2)*(c**2)))*(dd**3)) + (((-2*(b**2)*d)+((b**2)*(d**2)))*(dd**3)) +&
       (((-2*(b**2)*e)+((b**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**3)) + (((-2*(c**2)*d)+((c**2)*(d**2)))*(dd**2)) +&
       (((-2*(c**2)*e)+((c**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**2)) + (((-2*(d**2)*e)+((d**2)*(e**2)))*(dd)) +&
       (((4*(a**2)*b*c)+(-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*c)+(-2*(a**2)*b*(c**2))+((a**2)*(b**2)*(c**2)))*(dd**4)) +&
       (((4*(a**2)*b*d)+(-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*d)+(-2*(a**2)*b*(d**2))+((a**2)*(b**2)*(d**2)))*(dd**4)) +&
       (((4*(a**2)*b*e)+(-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*e)+(-2*(a**2)*b*(e**2))+((a**2)*(b**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**4)) +&
       (((4*(a**2)*c*d)+(-2*(a**2)*(c**2)*d)+(-2*(a**2)*c*(d**2))+((a**2)*(c**2)*(d**2)))*(dd**4)) +&
       (((4*(a**2)*c*e)+(-2*(a**2)*(c**2)*e)+(-2*(a**2)*c*(e**2))+((a**2)*(c**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**4)) +&
       (((4*(a**2)*d*e)+(-2*(a**2)*(d**2)*e)+(-2*(a**2)*d*(e**2))+((a**2)*(d**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**4)) +&
       (((4*(b**2)*c*d)+(-2*(b**2)*(c**2)*d)+(-2*(b**2)*c*(d**2))+((b**2)*(c**2)*(d**2)))*(dd**3)) +&
       (((4*(b**2)*c*e)+(-2*(b**2)*(c**2)*e)+(-2*(b**2)*c*(e**2))+((b**2)*(c**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**3)) +&
       (((4*(b**2)*d*e)+(-2*(b**2)*(d**2)*e)+(-2*(b**2)*d*(e**2))+((b**2)*(d**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**3)) +&
       (((4*(c**2)*d*e)+(-2*(c**2)*(d**2)*e)+(-2*(c**2)*d*(e**2))+((c**2)*(d**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**2)) +&
       (((-8*(a**2)*b*c*d)+(4*(a**2)*(b**2)*c*d)+(4*(a**2)*b*(c**2)*d)+(4*(a**2)*b*c*(d**2))+&
          (-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*(c**2)*d)+(-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*c*(d**2))+(-2*(a**2)*b*(c**2)*(d**2))+&
          ((a**2)*(b**2)*(c**2)*(d**2)))*(dd**4)) +&
       (((-8*(a**2)*b*c*e)+(4*(a**2)*(b**2)*c*e)+(4*(a**2)*b*(c**2)*e)+(4*(a**2)*b*c*(e**2))+&
          (-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*(c**2)*e)+(-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*c*(e**2))+(-2*(a**2)*b*(c**2)*(e**2))+&
          ((a**2)*(b**2)*(c**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**4)) +&
       (((-8*(a**2)*b*d*e)+(4*(a**2)*(b**2)*d*e)+(4*(a**2)*b*(d**2)*e)+(4*(a**2)*b*d*(e**2))+&
          (-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*(d**2)*e)+(-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*d*(e**2))+(-2*(a**2)*b*(d**2)*(e**2))+&
          ((a**2)*(b**2)*(d**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**4)) +&
       (((-8*(a**2)*c*d*e)+(4*(a**2)*(c**2)*d*e)+(4*(a**2)*c*(d**2)*e)+(4*(a**2)*c*d*(e**2))+&
          (-2*(a**2)*(c**2)*(d**2)*e)+(-2*(a**2)*(c**2)*d*(e**2))+(-2*(a**2)*c*(d**2)*(e**2))+&
          ((a**2)*(c**2)*(d**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**4)) +&
       (((-8*(b**2)*c*d*e)+(4*(b**2)*(c**2)*d*e)+(4*(b**2)*c*(d**2)*e)+(4*(b**2)*c*d*(e**2))+&
          (-2*(b**2)*(c**2)*(d**2)*e)+(-2*(b**2)*(c**2)*d*(e**2))+(-2*(b**2)*c*(d**2)*(e**2))+&
          ((b**2)*(c**2)*(d**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**3))  +&
       (((16*(a**2)*b*c*d*e)+(-8*(a**2)*(b**2)*c*d*e)+(-8*(a**2)*b*(c**2)*d*e)+(-8*(a**2)*b*c*(d**2)*e)+&
          (-8*(a**2)*b*c*d*(e**2))+(4*(a**2)*(b**2)*(c**2)*d*e)+(4*(a**2)*(b**2)*c*(d**2)*e)+&
          (4*(a**2)*(b**2)*c*d*(e**2))+(4*(a**2)*b*(c**2)*(d**2)*e)+(4*(a**2)*b*(c**2)*d*(e**2))+&
          (4*(a**2)*b*c*(d**2)*(e**2))+(-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*(c**2)*(d**2)*e)+(-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*(c**2)*d*(e**2))+&
          (-2*(a**2)*(b**2)*c*(d**2)*(e**2))+(-2*(a**2)*b*(c**2)*(d**2)*(e**2))+&
          ((a**2)*(b**2)*(c**2)*(d**2)*(e**2)))*(dd**4))
  A0 = 1 + bd + (dd*bd*Abar)
   f = (A0 - bd)/A0 !o(6)

!This program's lines are only for illustration. Scalar 'f' is closely related to an "N=6 problem" !
end program trialerror4
```

Finally, I first considered Matlab because its Editor allows long lines (before reaching its memory limits) and because the edition of these long equations in Fortran actually depends on the Fortran compiler's limits while concatenating the code lines. By the way, Evaluating long strings with eval was slow but useful until reaching Matlab's own memory limits with those string variables.

Comment: Without giving more information and reproducible example we cannot help you much ... but I can already tell you that using `eval` to evaluate long strings is probably the worst way to go about it, or at least the slowest as you already noticed ...

Comment: Without knowing anything else about your problem, I think you should consider using vector representations of these polynomials and matrix multiplication to evaluate them. e.g. evaluating the string  `6*x.^6 + 4*x.^4 + 2*x.^3 + 3*x.^2 + 8*x + 9` for (Mx1) vector `x` is equivalent to the following matrix multiplication in MATLAB : `x .^ [6:-1:0] * [6; 0; 4; 2; 3; 8; 9]`

Comment: Another general comment. If the problem is combinatorial in nature, the answer you seek is probably not O(N!) which would be your brute-force enumeration, but rather something more clever. For example you state the coefficients for `k = N+1` are related to the state `k = N`, this is a clue to me that recursion/memoization would be useful techniques. If I had to speculate I'd guess the solution you're looking for is O(log(N)) or O(N*log(N))

Comment: If you’re typing these things in an editor, you’re not using the software right. I cannot believe that any programming problem would require typing in repetitive lines of code. Software is supposed to avoid repetitive work. But you’ll have to share more about your problem if you want help with it. For example post the MATLAB code for a smaller version of your problem.

Comment: Der Chris, by looking at the hours of your comment and my re-edition of the problem, it is quite possible that you did not reach to take a look to the Fortran program I attached to it (for a small version of the problem). This code is showing everything but repetitive lines of code. It is just a sequence of an unusual poly that is kind of manageable for N=10, say, but then, as the polynomial become so big, Matlab editor kind of breaks down even though the function runs nicely. this is why I am coding it in Fortran. Best regards!

Comment: Generating equation =/= generating the string said equation should print to. You should avoid using `eval` in Matlab for any serious task.

Answer (score 0):

as you have taken a look to the Fortran program, you will probably be in agreement with the statement "Matlab Editor becomes really slow after big lines have to be processed, which kind of contrasts with the actual execution of the code." I agree that, in general, using string versions of commands to be executed with eval function has the problem of not having the help of the Editor's debugging warnings, so you can easily make coding mistakes. Having said that, your "[a] serious task" is an ambiguous statement in our context.